# Maven project to another maven projects dependencies

Tags: java, git, maven

I made a maven project as a core for all of my other "plugins".
 Now that it is time to start working on the plugins.
 However, I cannot find a way to add my maven project as a dependency to the other one. I know people have online repos for this but I cannot find any tutorial.
The core's pom can be found here: https://github.com/PhanaticGames/PhanaticSpigotCore/blob/master/pom.xml
The plugins pom can be found here:
https://github.com/PhanaticGames/PhanaticLobbyCore/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could you explain how?

Comment: It's reading and writing in your local maven repo (~/.m2/repository). Your external dependencies are also stored there (after being downloaded from online default repos)

Comment: Also, say if another dev on my team used the plugin's code and updated it, would this work for them aswell? Thanks Vivek

Comment: @MatthewParks - If you have a team of devs who need to share access to locally-authored artifacts(/dependencies): what you really should do is set up a Maven repository manager. The big players in this space are Nexus and Artifactory.  Each has a free version.  You can do without them, by having each dev manually communicate each version of each artifact to be imported into each others' local repos... but really, is this going to be easier than setting up a repo manager?  (Spoiler:  it will not.)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Any tutorials??

Comment: @MatthewParks just Google for Nexus.  They have detailed instruction on how to set up.  In your POM and settings.xml, you just need to set up deploymentDependency and server, and do `mvn deploy` to deploy to the nexus repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm beginner of Maven (Sadly,I cannot comment your question because of my reputation point).
If you want to get tutorial about project dependency and concept, these article might be help.

[Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/maven-the-definitive-guide-split-into-two-books/) is so grate guide to understand maven(maybe you already know this).
About project dependency, check out Book `Maven by Example`'s '6. A Multi-Module Project' and Book `Maven: The Complete Reference`'s '3.5 Project Relationships'.
 And you can download mvn-sample source in this book : [Chapter’s Example source](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip)

Here is extract of  '3.5 Project Relationships'

> One of the compelling reasons to use Maven is that it makes the process of tracking down dependencies 
>   (and dependencies of dependencies) very easy. When a project depends on an artifact produced by another 
>   project we say that this artifact is a dependency. In the case of a Java project, this can be as simple as a 
>   project depending on an external dependency like Log4J or JUnit. While dependencies can modelexternal 
>   dependencies, they can also manage the dependencies between a set of related projects. If project- 
>   a depends on project-b, Maven is smart enough to know that project-b must be built before 
>   project-a.
>
> Relationships are not only about dependencies and ﬁguring out what one project needs to be able to build 
>   an artifact. Maven can model the relationship of a project to a parent, and the relationship of a project to 
>   submodules. This section gives an overview of the various relationships between projects and how such 
>   relationships are conﬁgured.

And see also, Maven's official document- [Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)'s   Project Inheritance , Project Aggregation part.

Comment: Thanks. Super useful!